# How to send a file to specific user of multicast in Linux?

Tags: sockets, multicast

I found how to send a file to whole user in multicast, but I want to send a file to specific user. Is it possible? If so, please tell me how to do it.

I attached my source code shortly.

(I'm still not good at using StackOverflow, so please tell me how to be a better question)

```
sprintf(name, "%s", argv[3]);
memset(&mcast_group, 0x00, sizeof(mcast_group));

mcast_group.sin_family = AF_INET;
mcast_group.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &mcast_group.sin_addr);

read_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
send_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

mreq.imr_multiaddr = mcast_group.sin_addr;
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the multicast and send it to his IP address.